# How to control threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

The program is a message poster application that post rows to a site, as it should be speedy so i had to use multithreading..
But the issue is the number of threads can be from 10-100 so in case of high number of threads the probability of 2 threads taking the same row become possible.How can i avoid it? Which i just figure out looking at upto 11 rows posted with same ID which is not possible, other then what i am assuming above...

The way i am taking row is as follows:

1- Create Dataset From database....

2- Create counter ,rowCounter =0

```
   while (rowCounter < allPostingRows.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
            {

           //  Take rows, and increment rowcounter++
           //  Takes row according to row counter....
          //   get the value from the fields in dataset and run the function:
               postFunction(userName, pass, postUrl, rowCounter, worker, postTitle, postText, postTxtSnippet, groupID, dbID, postON, groupName, groupUrl);
             }
```

So if at start i say 100 threads to run this, 100 threads come into this code take a row each and post and when a thread posts and is free checks the `rowcounter` , and takes another row.

So i am using the above logic to give different rows to threads.Is this approach bad as i could not think of any other ! Also assuming multiple thread take same rows how can i fix that?

> UPDATE

One solution i can think of is to put random delay after all work done and the thread goes to take the new row which might help?

> UPDATE AFTER ANSWERED BY USER BELOW:

So my code should be like :

```
private Object thisLock = new Object();

   lock (thisLock)
            {
    while (rowCounter < allPostingRows.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
            {

           //  Take rows, and increment rowcounter++
           //  Takes row according to row counter....
          //   get the value from the fields in dataset and run the function:
               postFunction(userName, pass, postUrl, rowCounter, worker, postTitle, postText, postTxtSnippet, groupID, dbID, postON, groupName, groupUrl);
             }
          }
```

Comment: What does your program do? What is your input, and what is your output? Why are you using threads?

Comment: I woul reevaluate the need for threads here.  Unless you are having a genuine performance problem, you may not need multiple threads at all.  If your postFunction takes a long time, you should consider firing it asynchronously instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As L.B points out, I think `Parallel.ForEach` is your best bet.

Some things to note *why* and how to make sure you don't abuse ForEach.

An executing thread uses a particular CPU or Core.  Windows supports an arbitrary number of executing threads.  The number of threads can far exceed the number of cores.  If each thread is not CPU Bound, this isn't usually a problem because there's usually lots of horse power to go around.  A CPU Bound thread is one that is basically making use of 100% of the core it's running on. Each time Windows takes a core away from one thread to let another run is called a Context Switch.  A Context Switch is very time consuming, it has to halt a thread, save all the registers and other state information for the current thread, load saved registers and state information for another thread, then start up the other thread.  That's said to take as much as 1000 cycles itself.  When thread's aren't CPU bound, context switching is less likely; but, even when it does happen there's usually lots of CPU cycles to handle it.  When you have multiple CPU bound threads, they're using all the cycles they can get their hands on.  When you start taking cycles away simply to switch between threads, you can start to notice things actually taking longer.  If you have more CPU Bound threads than cores (i.e. you want to run "100" threads at a time) you'll actually take **more time** to execute the same amount of work if you had run all that work sequentially instead of parallel.

`Parallel.ForEach` does this automatically.  It knows it's a bad thing to have more CPU Bound threads than cores and only spins up as many threads to do parallel work than it sees fit.  (usually based on # of cores; but, it has a better idea of what else is going on in the TPL, so it may have other criteria that is uses).  You *can* coerce ForEach to use a specific number of threads, but you'll be defeating the purpose of parallelism *and* reducing your performance.

If you have 4 cores (or even 8 cores) and you run 100 CPU bound threads, the amount of CPU time devoted to context switching will be huge, and will likely bog down the system to an almost unusable state.

Comment: I understood your point but how can i show progress thn also pause and resumt?

Comment: To show progress, you'll have to use Control.BeginInvoke (or Control.Invoke if that won't cause a deadlock) to do invoke whatever code you need to update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this approach is "bad" and you will have the problematic thread situation you describe.  In fact, you could have all 100 threads get the same row before incrementing the counter.

> One solution i can think of is to put random delay after all work done
>   and the thread goes to take the new row which might help?

Not to be critical, but how do you think this is a solution?  I would suggest that you [read up on threads and synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyz69czz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the C# documentation to become more familiar with the topics.

Here are a couple of suggestions.

1)  Reverse the workflow.  Instead of creating the threads first, and having them come and fetch the data, have the main process parcel out the work to the threads as they are created.  That way the threads are never conflicting trying to access a shared resource, can die when they are finished, and new ones can be created at that time.

2)  If #1 doesn't work for you, then you need to consider the while loop in your code above as a "critical section", and place it inside of a [lock block.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   This will ensure only one thread is fetching a row and incrementing the counter at a given time.  However, depending on how fast the threads do their work, this can potentially make the process a lot less efficient.

Comment: By my solution i was assumin i put delay 1-50 sec , after a thread work is done ot goes to sleep , randomly any other with another random sleep so they wont match , but that i know is not a proper solution

Comment: If you're spinning up 100 threads, I strongly suggest that you *do* change your code. Spinning up that many threads is often counter productive. Consider using [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) instead (directly or via the [`Parallel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608.aspx) convenience class).

Comment: lock is fine, but it decreases the efficiency of your code.  99 threads will be waiting, doing nothing, while another thread is in that section of code.  The question is:  Why are you creating threads that are hanging around looking for more work after they are done their task?  What happens when the last row is finished?  Do you destroy them?  If you have a central "controlling" process that has a configurable max number of threads and parcels out the work, you will avoid all the problems of having these threads trying to access a shared resource.

Comment: @confusedMind: It isn't the lock that's the issue; it's the approach of indiscriminately creating threads. A thread is an expensive resource, and unless the machine you're running on has 100 CPU cores, there's no need for 100 threads. In any case, a lock is not even needed - you can easily dole out work to multiple threads (and get the results back) with `Parallel.ForEach()`.

Comment: agree again w/@AllonGuralnek.  The suggestions above are based on the fact that you already have code somewhere creating and dealing with threads.  lock will work for you.  If this is all you're using threading for though, I strongly agree with Allon.

Comment: @womp yes that is what i was going to ask now as i see tremendous decrease in speed...Yes once all the rows are finished the work is done all are closed...

Comment: 'unless the machine you're running on has 100 CPU cores, there's no need for 100 threads' - unless, say, the threads are blocked on network I/O, in which case 100 threads would supply a vast speedup on a single-core box.

Comment: ..or indeed, any I/O or inter-thread comms.  As I write this comment, my box has 4/8 cores and is 'running' 1122 threads, top process is 'System', with 241 threads.  Today, Kaspersky is next - 67 threads, then 'sidebar', with 66.  Seems like Kaspersky Labs and M$ are fine with many more threads than cores.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that the possibility 2 or more threads will read same row; however, i'm sure that you could use locking mechanism to protect the critical section. Moreover, ADO.NET will support [asynchronous task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211418%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to improve performance

Answer (score 0):

Agree with other commenters about using more intelligent partitioning such as the one provided by Parallel.ForEachr.
However, if you still want to use your code, consider putting the counter increment inside a critical region, or use CAS increment. Do it INSIDE the while loop, and not outside. For example:

```
while (rowCounter < allPostingRows.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref rowCounter);
                    //  Take rows, and increment rowcounter++            
                    //  Takes row according to row counter....           
                    //   get the value from the fields in dataset and run the function:                
                    postFunction(userName, pass, postUrl, rowCounter, worker, postTitle, postText, postTxtSnippet, groupID, dbID, postON, groupName, groupUrl);              
                }
```